# admob doesnot show ads

Tags: android, kotlin, admob

i a developing android app using kotlin and i added a banner 
i am not link the app to google play yet 
the problem the app on doesnot show any ads

how i show the ad 
 in main activity

```
 MobileAds.initialize(this, "APP ID FROM ADMOB")
 adView.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
```

in xml

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="7dp"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="UNIT ID FRO ADMOB" />
```

in android manifest xml

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value=""APP ID FROM ADMOB""/>
```

i test this code with app and unit id from tutorial and it is showing ads 
but with app and unit id doesnot show anything

this screen Shot from User metrics
[image: User metrics]

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement your ads properly. These(below) link help you to understand and implement Ads.

Even you not publish your app on playstore then always use *Test Ad id*.

**Visit:**

add sdk= https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start

implement banner ad= https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner